# Read contents of a selected Outlook e-mail using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I have this simple piece of code that reads the content of the last e-mail in my inbox.

How can I do the same for e-mail I click on/highlight within Outlook?

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
print(message.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Simply use **[ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.activeexplorer?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__Application_ActiveExplorer)***

*Example*

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
messages = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
message = messages(1)
print(message.body)
```